# Unable to update software on Ubuntu 19.10 / Dell XPS 7590

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, 19.10

`sudo apt update` command finishes with a lot of errors:

```
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_eoan-security_InRelease into data and signature failed
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi/ubuntu eoan InRelease
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_canonical-hwe-team_backport-iwlwifi_ubuntu_dists_eoan_InRelease into data and signature failed
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu eoan InRelease
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_linrunner_tlp_ubuntu_dists_eoan_InRelease into data and signature failed
Reading package lists... Error!
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_eoan-security_InRelease into data and signature failed
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi/ubuntu eoan InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ppa.launchpad.net_canonical-hwe-team_backport-iwlwifi_ubuntu_dists_eoan_InRelease into data and signature failed
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi/ubuntu eoan InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu eoan InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_linrunner_tlp_ubuntu_dists_eoan_InRelease into data and signature failed
E: Clearsigned file '/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_linrunner_tlp_ubuntu_dists_eoan_InRelease' contains unsigned lines.
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

It used to work fine, I did not change my repositories since then.

- Is it a security issue?
- How can I resolve this error and do not harm the security of my system?

---

[image]

---

UPDATE: `sudo apt autoremove` gives error:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Clearsigned file '/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_linrunner_tlp_ubuntu_dists_eoan_InRelease' contains unsigned lines.
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: 19.04 is EOL. The latest version 20.04 LTS will be released late April 2020

Comment: Your pasted messages mention `eoan` or 19.10, so please clarify.

Comment: I edited my question: I have ubuntu 19.10. sorry for this error.

Comment: @guiverc ok, let's remove tlp PPA.

Comment: Nah Sorry, I think I made an error, check it first..

Comment: another update: `apt autoremove` doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

Your GPG problem is an easy one. Your signatures are incorrect. Update them with:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

Please do that with every wrong key by just changing the last key number and keeping the rest.

Rebuild your software cache:

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
```